# maintaining correct aspect ratio on full screen height image

Tags: image, slider, height, aspect-ratio

I have two divs with width of 30% and 70% and fixed height as height:100vh; Because the project needs to have the slider to be always the height of the screen you are looking at.

But I cant seem to figure out how to fix the aspect ratio of the images? As you can see in the test link that the images are narrow?

here is the link : [broken link removed]

note that this is the prototype that I am building so its still ugly as **** :)

and sorry im not too good at coding (still learning)

Answer (score 1):

Your image is stretching because you've set both the width and height to 100%, so the browser is making the image width fit the div width (which is thinner than the aspect ratio of your image).

The quick fix is to amend your CSS as follows:

```
.cycle-slideshow img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

This tells the browser to set the height to 100% and then resize the width accordingly to keep the image the correct aspect ratio.

Although, you may want some fall back for if the browser window is much wider than it is tall, as then you'll see the edge of the image.

Comment: Hi, I put the changes ( i did something simillar with the same effect) but now the width ot the pic becomes way way to big and I want to keep it to be with a witdh of 70% of the screen. Is there a way to make the pic crop the excess ? 

the changes are live so u can see how looks

Comment: Add `height: 100%` to `.cycle-slideshow`. If the element the `img` sits within doesn't have a set height, when you set the image to `height: 100%` the browser thinks you mean the full image height rather than fill the height of the containing element. Seeing as the original answer answered your original question, could you click on the 'tick' icon to show that it's been answered. Cheers.